# Calloc vs. malloc for pointer to struct

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

In dynamically allocating memory for a struct, I ran across some code that does

```c
struct simulation *sim_one = calloc(1, sizeof(*sim_one));
```

Is there any reason to prefer using `calloc` over `malloc` for structs? In this context, do they do the same thing? Also, I've only ever seen `sizeof` called with a datatype; however, the `calloc` example calls `sizeof` on a pointer to a variable `sim_one` which, I would think, doesn't exist at the moment when `sizeof` is called, but compilation and execution leads to no errors. See below for the `malloc` example.

```c
struct simulation *sim_two = malloc(sizeof(struct simulation));
```

The latter option is syntax for which I am familiar from allocations such as `double *var = malloc(sizeof(double))`.

I define the structs here for clarity:

```c
struct particle {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

struct simulation {
  struct particle particles[100];
};

int main(){
  struct simulation *sim_one = calloc(1, sizeof(*sim_one));       // why?
  struct simulation *sim_two = malloc(sizeof(struct simulation)); // familiar malloc syntax
}
```

Comment: Too often `xxx *p = malloc( sizeof( xxx ) );` is overlooked when 'p' is changed to point to 'yyy'... The new-to-you version `xxx *p = malloc( sizeof *p );` has less maintenance and less chance for overlooking the required change when `yyy *p = malloc....` is required.

Comment: PS: `sizeof` is a compile time operator. It is not a runtime function that is "_called_."

Comment: @Jared Frazier, With `struct simulation *sim_one = calloc(1, sizeof(*sim_one));`, `sim_one` exist at the end of `struct simulation *sim_one`, so " variable `sim_one` which, I would think, doesn't exist at the moment when sizeof is called," is amiss.

Comment: @Jared Frazier, I recommend you use the `pointer = malloc(sizeof pointer[0] * n)` syntax. It is easier to code right, review and maintain than `pointer = malloc(n * sizeof (*pointer_type))`.